# Add callback method to observer dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, metaprogramming, observer-pattern

I want to create matcher that test whether a model is watched by observer.

I decided to dynamically add method `after_create` (if necessary), save instance of model and check is it true that observer instance received an `after_create` call. Simplified version ([full version](https://gist.github.com/petRUShka/cbad53eab23ca680516d/9e4f474a508b0a3b880eb9924894ea78556facc6)) :

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_observed_by do |observer_name|
  match do |obj|
    ...

    observer.class_eval do
      define_method(:after_create) {}
    end  

    observer.instance.should_receive(:after_create)

    obj.save(validate: false)

    ...

    begin
      RSpec::Mocks::verify  # run mock verifications
      true
    rescue RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError => e
      # here one can use #{e} to construct an error message
      false
    end
  end
end
```

It wasn't work. No instance of observer is received `after_create` call.

But If I modify actual code of Observer in `app/models/user_observer.rb` like this

```
class UserObserver
  ...
  def after_create end
  ...
end
```

It works as expected.

What should I do to add `after_create` method dynamically to force trigger observer after create?

Comment: Why whould you test behavior that is part of standard Rails? This is generally considered unnecessary since it's already covered in the Rails test suite.

Comment: @Martijn, I don't really try to test Rails. My goal is to check somehow that this particular observer is setup properly (in config of rails) and truly observe `User` model. I consider this as behavior and I want to test it (see Chelimsky opinion on similar topic: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/02/12/validations-are-behavior-associations-are-structure/). The approach above is the only way I see to reach this goal. So if there is another way to do it I would be happy!

Comment: P.S. I want to test my observers in isolation. Hence I need to be sure that this observer really observe `User` model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, this behavior is due to the fact that Rails hooks up UserObserver callbacks to User events at the initialization time. If the `after_create` callback is not defined for UserObserver at that time, it will not be called, even if later added.

If you are interested in more details on how that observer initialization and hook-up to the wobserved class works, at the end I posted a brief walk-through through the Observer implementation. But before we get to that, here is a way to make your tests work. Now, I'm not sure if you want to use that, and not sure why you decided to test the observer behavior in the first place in your application, but for the sake of completeness...

After you do `define_method(:after_create)` for observer in your matcher insert the explicit call to `define_callbacks` (a protected method; see walkthrough through the Observer implementatiin below on what it does) on observer instance. Here is the code:

```
observer.class_eval do
  define_method(:after_create) { |user| }
end
observer.instance.instance_eval do          # this is the added code
  define_callbacks(obj.class)               # - || -
end                                         # - || -
```

### A brief walk-through through the Observer implementation.

Note: I'm using the "rails-observers" gem sources (in Rails 4 observers were moved to an optional gem, which by default is not installed). In your case, if you are on Rails 3.x, the details of implementation may be different, but I believe the idea will be the same.

First, this is where the observers' instantiation is launched: https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/blob/master/lib/rails/observers/railtie.rb#L24. Basically, call `ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers` in `ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record)`, i.e. when the ActiveRecord library is loaded.

In the same file you can see how it takes the `config.active_record.observers` parameter normally provided in the `config/application.rb` and passes it to the `observers=` defined here: https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/blob/master/lib/rails/observers/active_model/observing.rb#L38

But back to `ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers`. It just cycles through all defined observers and calls `instantiate_observer` for each of them.  Here is where the `instantiate_observer` is implemented: https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/blob/master/lib/rails/observers/active_model/observing.rb#L180. Basically, it makes a call to `Observer.instance` (as a Singleton, an observer has a single instance), which will initialize that instance if that was not done yet.

This is how Observer initialization looks like: https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/blob/master/lib/rails/observers/active_model/observing.rb#L340. I.e. a call to `add_observer!`.

You can see `add_observer!`, together with and `define_callbacks` that it calls, here: https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/blob/master/lib/rails/observers/activerecord/observer.rb#L95.

This `define_callbacks` method goes through all the callbacks defined in your observer class (UserObserver) **at that time** and creates `"_notify_#{observer_name}_for_#{callback}"` methods for the observed class (User), and register them to be called on that event in the observed class (User, again).

In your case, it should have been `_notify_user_observer_for_after_create` method added as `after_create` callback to User. Inside, that `_notify_user_observer_for_after_create` would call `update` on the UserObserver class, which in turn would call `after_create` on UserObserver, and all would work from there.

But, in your case `after_create` doesn't exist in `UserObserver` during Rails initialization, so no method is created and registered for `User.after_create` callback. Thus, no luck after that with catching it in your tests. That little mystery is solved.